# Why am i receiving error 404 when fetching video data?

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, restful-url

I'm trying to display the video which is in mp4 format of the code's folder. When i try to fetch the video by clicking on the button it shows an empty space but doesn't display the video.[display of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vkld8.png)

The error i'm receiving from the console: **GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapi/myapi1/undefined 404 (Not Found)**

Below is the url to display the json data:
http://localhost:8080/myapi/myapi1/user/1

The link above displays:

```
{"videoName":"video.mp4"}
```

The code to fetch the video and display using ajax:

```
$('#room1').on('click',function (e){
                    $.ajax({
                    
                    method: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/myapi/myapi1/user/1",
                    success: function(data) {
                        var student = '';

                    // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        
                        // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
                        student += '<video height="603"';
                           
                        student += 'src="' + 
                            value.videoName + '" autoplay loop muted></video>';
                    });
                    
                   
                    $('#video').append(student);
                    },
                    error:function(exception){alert('Exeption:'+exception);}
                    })
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

Comment: Can you try hard-refreshing the page to clear the cache? Ctrl (or Cmd) + R

Comment: can you print the data variable in the console and add the response?

Comment: @brice tried, but am still receiving the same error

Comment: @AdisonMasih the response i received: undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, The data you are fetching is in JSON ENCODED FORMAT. so you need to parse it to a JS Object. like this: `data = JSON.parse(data)` in your `success` function.

Comment: i have added as suggested:   `success: function(data = JSON.parse(data))`  but i am still receiving the same error.

Comment: not like that. add `data = JSON.parse(data)` inside the success function body.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Since you only have one data item returned, please change the success block from:

```
success: function(data) {
var student = '';

// ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        
// DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
student += '<video height="603"';
                           
student += 'src="' + 
value.videoName + '" autoplay loop muted></video>';
});
                    
$('#video').append(student);
},
```

to

```
success: function(data) {
var student = '';

                        
// DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
student += '<video height="603"';
                           
student += 'src="' + 
data.videoName + '" autoplay loop muted></video>';
                    
$('#video').append(student);
},
```

**data.videoName** is already the data (video filename) you need

(2) However, if you have multiple data, like the following:

```
[{"videoName":"video.mp4"}, {"videoName":"video1.mp4"}]
```

then you may use the following :

```
success: function(data) {
var student = '';

 for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {   
                        
// DATA FROM JSON OBJECT
student += '<video height="603"';
                           
student += 'src="' + 
data[x].videoName + '" autoplay loop muted></video>';

}
                    
$('#video').append(student);
},
```

**data[index].videoName** will be the data (video file name) for each index

(3) If you still prefer to use key / value pairs, the correct syntax will be like:

```
 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
  alert(data[key].videoName);
})
```

Comment: Great explanation, thank you. May i know why the code I provided produces error? It worked fine with a non-restful backend.